# Axios Put Request Not Updating Data | React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I have been working on a project where I am trying to update my selected data but Axios didn't Update it even after giving a success msg.

***User Response*** it returns from axios:-

```
completed: true
date: "2021-02-28"
mupp_path: "PATH 1 - LIVING YOUR WHY - Build/Apply/Inspire/Spread (BAIS) – Finding &amp; Achieving Meaning and Purpose in work and life"
project_name: "Design and Test the Training Content for the i-Infinity 3 verticals "
selected: true
task_id: 14
task_name: "This is adding a new task to chekc full inbox functionality "
task_type: "THIS_WEEK"
```

**Actions.js**

```
export const taskTodayUnselect = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: types.UNSELECTED_TASK_TODAY_REQUEST });
        const { data } = await axios.put(
            selectTaskForToday,
            {
                task_id: id,
                selected: false,
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `JWT ${token}`,
                },
            }
        );
        if (data) {
            return dispatch({ type: types.UNSELECTED_TASK_TODAY_SUCCESS, payload: data });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return dispatch({ type: types.UNSELECTED_TASK_TODAY_FAILURE, payload: error });
    }
};
```

**thisweek.js**

```
export default function ThisWeek() {

    const unselectTaskTodayAPI = (id) => {
        dispatch(taskTodayUnselect(id)).then((response) => {
            let result = response.payload;
            console.log(result);
            if (result.success === 'true') {
                notifySuccess(result.message);
                fetchTaskData(categoryID);
            }
        });
    };
const selectTask = (item) => {
        if (item.selected) {
            unselectTaskTodayAPI(item);
            console.log('unselect');
        } else {
            selectTaskTodayAPI(item.task_id);
        }
    };

return (
                                    <TaskDataComponent
                                        item={item}
                                        key={item.task_id}
                                        label="This Week"
                                        selectTask={selectTask}
                                    />
);
```

> Don't Worry about the TaskDataComponent , it only handle the onClick function which invoke the selectedTask function

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const data = (await axios.put(...)).data` ? Not sure though

Comment: Thanks, @JeremyThille for your effort but I don't think it affects my code anyhow because it is returning successful response. even but didn't updated the data.